# Картинка кодируемая в base64 в андройде не декодируется в php base64_decode

Tags: php, java, android, base64

Я кодирую на стороне клbента Bitmap в  base64

```
    public String toBase64FromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap){
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 65, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream .toByteArray();

    String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encoded;
}
```

Затем данные отправляю на сервер

```
$request = $_GET;


if (isset($request['base64'])) {
    $fileTmpPath = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($request['base64']));
```

и получаю ошибку

> Warning: imagecreatefromstring(): gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports
> unrecoverable error: Unsupported marker type 0xf6 in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\api\v1\profile\base64upload.php on line 22
>
> Warning: imagecreatefromstring(): Passed data is not in 'JPEG' format
> in C:\xampp\htdocs\api\v1\profile\base64upload.php on line 22
>
> Warning: imagecreatefromstring(): Couldn't create GD Image Stream out
> of Data in C:\xampp\htdocs\api\v1\profile\base64upload.php on line 22
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: message in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\api\v1\profile\base64upload.php on line 66

Comment: Вы её query-параметром что-ли передаёте? Сравните длину строки сразу после кодирования и перед декодированием. Если картинка большая, то возможно она не умещается в лимит URL-строки, заданный Андроидом,  сервером или кем-то ещё.

Comment: я ее и постом пробовал а с длинной всё отлично,картинка маленькая!

Comment: Если можно постом, то зачем извращаться с кодированием - передайте оригинал.

Comment: нашёл ошибку,почему-то пробелы приходят вместо текста=_=

Comment: + заменяются на пробелы=_=

Answer (score 0):

Надо заменить все пробелы на +

```
str_replace(" ","+",$request['base64']);
```

Comment: А может надо заменить флаг `Base64.DEFAULT` на `Base64.URL_SAFE`?

Comment: для меня не сработало,но я оставлю его на всякий ,для будущего!

Answer (score 0):

```
 надо заменить флаг Base64.DEFAULT на Base64.URL_SAFE
```